# Is it possible to combine PHP's filter_input() filter flags with AND/OR?

Tags: php

Various [filter flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) can be used with PHP's [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function.

For example, if I want to retrieve the value of a scalar POST field, I can use the default, without specifying the filter. Or, if I I'm dealing with an array POST field, I'd use the corresponding filter:

```
$scalar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'field');
$array = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'field', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

Is it possible to combine the filter flags with either `AND` or `OR`? For example, with `OR`:

```
$value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'field', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR || FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

A possible use case for this would be looping over POST fields, some of which can be arrays. e.g.,

```
foreach ($fieldSet as $field)
{
    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $field, FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR || FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    ...
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php: “options: Associative array of options or bitwise disjunction of flags.”

Comment: Using bitwise operator in `FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR | FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` on an array POST field returns false.

Comment: Well that is to be expected, because nothing is a scalar _and_ an array at the same time. That you _can_ combine _all_ filters this way, doesn’t necessarily mean that every combination also makes sense.

Comment: I understand that, which is why I'm asking if this is possible for `OR` as well. Something can be a scalar *or* an array.

Comment: Maybe use ternary operator ? `$value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'field', FILTER_DEFAULT, is_array($_POST['field']) ? FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY : NULL);`

Comment: No, there is no OR. _“Something can be a scalar or an array”_ – then test it for whether it is the one thing, or it is the other, by logically joining two filter_input calls.

Comment: I can conduct *all the tests in the world* to check this. My question is is it possible to combine the filter flags as explained.

Comment: I believe, `filter_input()` is too limited and it's better to take some custom solution. Symfony has good components for this.

Answer (score 0):

How about a slightly different approach:

```
$filtered = array();
//loop through all the posted values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  //apply a different filter for arrays and scalars
  if(is_array($value)) {
    $filtered[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, {filters for array});
  }
  else {
    $filtered[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, {filters for scalar});
  }
}
```

You could also combine this with a set of per-field filters if you wanted to exclude anything else that was sent:

```
//define the filters
$filters = array(
  'field1' => FILTER_DEFAULT | FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
  'field2' => FILTER_DEFAULT | FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
  ...etc
);

$filtered = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  //only include a value if a filter definition exists for the key
  if(array_key_exists($key, $filters)) {
    $filtered[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, $filters[$key]);
  }
}
```